# Show that a finite dimensional vector space (V) has some basis (B) whose subset (B') is a basis for some subspace of V (W)

Tags: linear-algebra

I must prove that given a finite dimensional vector space $V$ and a subspace $W$ of $V$, there exists a basis $B$ of $V$ such that a subset $B'$ of $B$ is a basis of $W$.

Here's what I know:

Let's say V has dimension n.

The proof that a finite dimensional vector space has a basis is trivial.

- W is closed under addition and scalar multiplication and if $W = {w_1,w_2,...,w_m} (m\le n)$ then  $c_1w_1+c_2w_2+...+c_mw_m \in W$ (where $c_m \in \Bbb{R}$)
- basis B is linearly independent, and $span(B) = V$, and $|B| = n$
- B' is also linearly independent
- For some spanning set of V (let's say S) and some linearly independent subset of V (let's say T), $|T| \le dim(V) \le |S|$

From here, I have absolutely no clue what to do. I can't seem to find the "link" between B and W that will allow me to remove elements from B to get a B' that spans W.

Comment: Please add the complet statement you are trying to prove to the body of your question.

Comment: Is it given that there is a vector space V with a basis B and a subspace W or that there is a vector space V with a basis B and a subset B'

Comment: Please put what you want to prove and what is given to you **at the begining** of your post, so that it is comprehensible! surely it would seem odd to you to read a bunch of text which only tells you what its point is at the very end?

Answer (score 1):

Let $B'$ be any basis of the subspace $W$ and complete $B'$ to a basis $B$ of $V$.

**Lemma.** If $B'$ is a linearly independent subset of a finite dimensional vector space $V$, then there exists a basis $B$ of $V$ such that $B\supseteq B'$.